# Как называется программа (по иконке в описании)

Tags: поиск-программ

[image: Иконка]

Как называется приложение у которого левый верхний угол синий правый нижний зеленый а по центру замок

Comment: WinSCP это если я не ошибаюсь https://winscp.net/eng/download.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Эта программа называется WinSCP